# How to select all QTreeWidgetItem widgets automatically

Tags: python, pyqt

This code creates `QTreeWidget` with `QComboBox` and `QLineEdit` set as `item widgets` (using `setItemWidget()` method).
Clicking an item's name ('Item_1', 'Item_2' and etc) makes the item "selected" but its item widgets stay deselected. Is there any `QTreeWidgetItem` flag or an attribute to set so when the item is clicked all its item-widgets are selected automatically?

[image]

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

class Tree(QtGui.QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Tree, self).__init__()
        for each in ['Item_1','Item_2','Item_3','Item_4','Item_5']:
            item=QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem([each])
            self.addTopLevelItem(item)
            self.setItemWidget(item, 1, QtGui.QComboBox())
            self.setItemWidget(item, 2, QtGui.QLineEdit())
        self.setColumnCount(5)
        self.resize(360,240)
        self.show()

tree=Tree()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can implemented SIGNAL `void itemClicked (QTreeWidgetItem*,int)` when the item is clicked 1 its item-widgets are selected automatically. In this case I select `QLineEdit` automatically.

First, connect SIGNAL `void itemClicked (QTreeWidgetItem*,int)` of `QTreeWidget`.
Last, get curent iten widget form current `QTreeWidgetItem` ans set it focus.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Tree(QtGui.QTreeWidget):
    ENUM_COMBOBOX = 1
    ENUM_LINEEDIT = 2
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Tree, self).__init__()
        for each in ['Item_1','Item_2','Item_3','Item_4','Item_5']:
            item=QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem([each])
            self.addTopLevelItem(item)
            self.setItemWidget(item, self.ENUM_COMBOBOX, QtGui.QComboBox())
            self.setItemWidget(item, self.ENUM_LINEEDIT, QtGui.QLineEdit())
        self.setColumnCount(5)
        self.resize(360,240)
        self.show()
        self.connect(self, QtCore.SIGNAL('itemClicked (QTreeWidgetItem *, int)'), self.itemClickedEvent)

    def itemClickedEvent (self, currentQTreeWidgetItem, column):
        currentQWidget = self.itemWidget(currentQTreeWidgetItem, self.ENUM_LINEEDIT)
        currentQWidget.setFocus()

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
tree=Tree()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**itemClicked  method Reference** : http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtreewidget.html#itemClicked

---

Regards,